# How to get elements positioned nearby in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frontend

I am trying to build a confetti where elements would be dropping (animated to translateY) in a random fashion. I have a button around which i would like to avoid elements falling on top of in such a way that if any of the dropping confetti is near this block, it should be deviated from its path. Javascript does provide this function called document.elementFromPoint(x,y) but this gives me only an exact position. I rather am looking for elements within this complete range.

I have tried looking for elements at certain point using document.elementFromPoint(x,y) but that just gives me element at that exact position. I wish to avoid putting a handle on all the falling(animated) elements.

```
var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y - 30);

if (elementMouseIsOver.className.indexOf('confetti') >= 0){
//change confetti left position here.
}
```

I expect this should not check for exact one position but the entire range nearby.